# iMac retina 27" with Mac OS X Yosemite. Reduce space between lines in Pages

Tags: macos, imac, pages

When using the Pages app, how can I reduce the space between lines of text to
LESS than single spacing?

Answer (score 1):

Select Format on the icon menu bar, and then under Spacing Lines adjust the distance to your requirements.

[image]

This is an example:

[image]